# How to list all files that include a header file

Tags: c, header-files

Standard cscope search for "Find files #including this file"

returns only those matches where foo.h is directly included in bar.c

But I am interested in all those files that directly or indirectly

(e.g. including a header file that includes foo.h) include foo.h

Answer (score 4):

If you're using GCC, run [`cpp -H`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258826/how-to-see-the-actual-order-of-include-files-after-preprocessing/5258938#5258938) on all modules and `grep` for the header you want:

```
header=foo.h

# *.c or all interesting modules
for i in *.c; do
    # there's bound to be a cleaner regex for this
    cpp -H "$i" 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q "^\.* .*/$header" && echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: +1 thanks, a lifesaver diagnosing a problem in a project with a huge #include tree

Answer (score 1):

This SO post might help you out:

[make include directive and dependency generation with -MM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801532/make-include-directive-and-dependency-generation-with-mm)

Basically, make can generate a list of all dependancies in a project.  I use the following in all my make files:

```
# Generate dependencies for all files in project
%.d: $(program_SRCS)
    @ $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM $*.c | sed -e 's@^\(.*\)\.o:@\1.d \1.o:@' > $@

clean_list += ${program_SRCS:.c=.d}

# At the end of the makefile
# Include the list of dependancies generated for each object file
# unless make was called with target clean
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include ${program_SRCS:.c=.d}
endif
```

An example of what this does.  Let's say you have foo.cpp that includes foo.h which includes bar.h which includes baz.h.  The above would generate the file foo.d and include it in your make file.  The dependancy file foo.d would look like this:

```
foo.d foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h baz.h
```

This way both make and you can see the full build dependancy chain for any particular object file.

Then to find all files which include a particular header just `grep -l foo.h *.d` to find out which source files include foo.h.