# Is there a way to detect when file dependencies are "accidentally" satisfied?

Tags: c, header, include

Let's say there are three headers `AAA.h`, `BBB.h` and `MyLib.h`. `MyLib.h` needs to include both `AAA.h` and `BBB.h` to work properly.

Now, it just happens that `BBB.h` also includes `AAA.h` in it, but this is strictly due to the implementation, a detail that `MyLib.h` should not need to care about.

However, by mistake, the writer of `MyLib.h` neglects to include `AAA.h` and never notices. This normally doesn't result in an error or warning, for as far as I know. Later on, someone changes the implementation details of `BBB.h` so that `AAA.h` is no longer needed and thus removed. Now MyLib doesn't compile because internals of library BBB have changed.

Is there a way to error or warn in cases like these? I suspect (if this is even possible) that it would take some kind of annotation in the header being included.

Comment: You're right it would require annotation, since sometimes headers are *documented* to include other headers, or headers are internally implemented by including other files. You wouldn't want to wade through a lot of false positives because your code relies on something defined in `/compiler/internals/stl_vector_impl.h`, when all your app included was `<vector>`, or where user-defined libraries have followed a similar organization.

Comment: GCC has an option to see which headers are including which others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258826/how-to-see-the-actual-order-of-include-files-after-preprocessing/5258938#5258938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is best to avoid depending on other headers in public interface headers, so that this problem does not come up.

Public interface headers should not contain unnecessary definitions.

There are various tricks to do things without include files. For example, you can declare struct tags manually if you just need a pointer (libraries that only define a typedef frustrate this) and you can use `_Bool` instead of `bool` to avoid `<stdbool.h>`. Unfortunately, many important types such as `size_t` and `uint32_t` are only defined in headers.

Some packages go so far as to define their own `foo_uint32_t` using configure so they need not include `<stdint.h>` in their public interface headers. This is quite tricky since the types must be exactly the same to avoid confusion: even if `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` they are different types. Therefore, it may not be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You are illustrating why including headers sucks as a method to import namespaces.

The only solution I see is discipline. Standard library functions require that you include the appropriate header, your projects should adopt the same standard. Headers such as `MyLib.h` should contain only the types it defines and its function prototypes. If it needs to use a certain type to do it's job, the header should be included explicitly, so if it needs a definition from `AAA` it should include `AAA.h` and if it needs some definition from `BBB` it should include `BBB.h`, likewise any implementation files (let's say `MyLib.c`) should explicitly include all the headers for any definitions it uses, regardless of being sure that `MyLib.h` is including them as well. **Never assume that a header defines anything implicitly** by including other headers.

This is easily checkable using an IDE, which will usually tell you where a name is defined and thus you can easily figure out which include file to use. There may be tools available that do this kind of checking.